# Add current class for future date

Tags: php

I have a list of events that start and begin on different dates.

1. 04.12.2015–03.01.2016
2. 08.01.2016–14.02.2016
3. 26.02.2016–27.03.2016

And I have a piece of code, that adds a current-event class for a single event if its between some dates.

```
$startDate = get_post_meta('_event_start_date', true);
$endDate = get_post_meta('_event_end_date', true);
$currentDate = current_time( 'mysql' );

if ( ($currentDate > $startDate) && ($currentDate < $endDate) ) {
    return 'current-event';
} else {
    return '';
}
```

This all works fine and does its job, but what I've encountered is that between two events there isn't any dates to compare. For example, if today's date is the 5th of January and the next event is starting at 8th of January, it doesn't add a current-event class to the future event. I guess I'd have to add another elseif statement to the code, but with what should I compare it with?

Just to bring out the case here, that I'd like to add the current-event class for only one future event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
if ( ($currentDate > $startDate) && ($currentDate < $endDate) ) {
    return 'current-event';
} else if($currentDate < $startDate) {
    return 'current-event';
} else  {
    return '';
}
```

//version 2:

```
$startDate = get_post_meta('_event_start_date', true);
$endDate = get_post_meta('_event_end_date', true);
$currentDate = current_time( 'mysql' );

$startDays = array();      //assign your start days to this array & sort it as well

if ( ($currentDate > $startDate) && ($currentDate < $endDate) ) {
    return 'current-event';
} else {
    foreach($startDays as $day)
    {
        if($currentDate < $day)
        {
           /*
           this will return current event for the exactly next event (and not for the other next events).
           but make sure to sort the dates in the start days array.
           */
            return 'current-event';         
            break;
        }else
        {
            return '';    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost, but the problem with this is that it also adds the current-event class to all future events. I didn't emphesize that I'd only like to add the class it to a single future event.

Comment: I though of a way to do that, check if it suits you.